# Treating categorical data to avoid dimensionality problem for KNN

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, dimensionality-reduction, k-nearest-neighbour

I'm new to machine learning and advanced statistics so please be patient with my basic question.

I am currently trying to model a data set I have with bunch of time data as independent variables  (i.e. hour, day, month and year). With a continuous variable as the outcome, i.e. money.

My understanding is that you must convert categorical variables for knn to work.

Does that mean I must somehow convert my time data? The approach I found online was basically convert every level of a categorical variable to be a binary. But given the many possible levels, doesn't this create the dimensionality problem?

Is this a common problem with knn? Should I just use a different algorithm? Or should I seek to combine my time data into one continuous variable somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Designing a distance metric is a common problem in KNN. A common distance metric for categorical variables is the **Gower distance**.

However, it's more efficient to merge your hour/day/month/year variables into a single date variable. A very common implementation is **Excel date serial number** (google details if you want to learn more), it's used in finance and many other applications.

If you were able to do the merging, you'd have a numeric variable representing your date. You can then use KNN easily with this date variable.

Comment: A couple good options here (+1). One thing to think about when deciding whether to merge the hour/day/etc. into a single value is how the output depends on these fields. For example, keeping a separate hour feature lets you treat all examples that occur near 8am as being similar along this dimension. If the output fluctuates hourly, this can be useful. Collapsing to a single time value would treat these examples as unique, obscuring this relationship. OTOH, if the output is a long-timescale trend, hours would be irrelevant and including them as a dimension would just add noise.